# In electrostatic potential, on charges $q$ & $Q$, work $W$ is done to move $q$ (towards $Q$) without net force, what is stored as potential energy?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, work, potential-energy

Text book cites when defining electrostatic potential, we give $W$ amount of work, so that the test charge, q (negligible force on Q) is brought near the source charge, Q and that no net force or acceleration is produced. But when there is no work done on q, the force due to Q will take the test charge away, the stored energy of the test charge is used for its movement. If all the work goes into opposing the repulsive forces of attraction where does the potential energy of the test charge come from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two concepts, potential and potential energy, and not defining the system that you are considering.

When considering a situation in Physics you should define a system.
In this case the system might be the test charge $q$ alone or it could be fi8xed charge $Q$ and test charge $q$.

**System - test charge $q$ alone**
There are two external forces acting on the test charge.
The electrostatic force due to the charge $Q$ and a force which is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to the electrostatic force, say the force that you exert in moving the test charge.
In moving the test charge the net work done by the two forces is zero so there is no change in the kinetic energy of the test charge.
When the test charge moves from a arbitrarily chosen position at zero potential to another position, then the potential (not potential energy) at the new position is defined in one of two ways:
the work done on the test charge by the force that you exerted, divided by charge $q$,
or
minus the work done on the test charge by the force exerted by charge $Q$, divided by charge $q$.

**System - test charge $q$ and charge $Q$**
The only external force in this case is the force that you exert on the test charge $q$.
The change in potential energy of the system of two charges when moving the test charge $q$ between two positions is equal to the work done by you in moving charge $q$.
The potential energy is stored in the electric field generated by the system of two charges.
Thus if you release the test charge and it moves position, the change in potential energy of the system of two charges is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the test charge.